# Can I obtain a task in KEXT?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

Just wondering if it is possible to obtain a task for a given proc_t inside a kext.
I have tried task_for_pid() which didn't work for some reason that I don't remember.
I tried proc_task(proc_t p) from sys/proc.h but I can't load my kext since that function is not exported.

I guess that I'm doing something wrong but I can't quite figure out what. Assuming I can get the task for a process, I'd like to use some mach calls and allocate memory, write memory and whatnot but for that, I would need the task I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a public direct `proc_t`->`task_t` lookup KPI, unfortunately.

However, in some cases, you might be able to get away with using `current_task()` and holding on to that pointer for as long as you need it. Use `task_reference` and `task_deallocate` for reference counting (but don't hold references forever obviously, otherwise they'll never be freed). You can also access the kernel's task (corresponding to process 0) anytime via the global variable `kernel_task`.

Comment: It's interesting to see that you can access the task from a user land perspective and do all sorts of things but you can't do the same from a KEXT. Coming from the Windows world, this is a little counter intuitive :) but I'm learning stuff every day.

Comment: Yeah, I get the impression there's fairly little system behind what is a public KPI and what isn't. I suspect at one point Apple decided what kinds of kext it wanted to allow 3rd party developers to create, and basically just compiled a list of symbols required by Apple's own kexts of those kinds, and made them public. Various odds and ends have been added since.

Answer (score 4):

After some research it would appear that it's not the case.
There is proc_task() defined in proc.h but it's under the #ifdef KERNEL_PRIVATE. The KEXT will compile albeit the warning.

In order to use that function, you have to add the com.apple.kpi.private in the list of dependencies but even that will fail since you are most likely NOT Apple :)

*Only Apple kexts may link against com.apple.kpi.private.*

Anyway, the experiment was interesting in the sense that other APIs such as vm_read, vm_write etc. are not available to use inside a KEXT (which probably makes sense since they are declared in a vm_user.h and I suppose are reserved for user mode).